# b.barracudacentral.org how configure my firewall

Tags: spam, barracuda

I use a ZyXEL USG200 firewall and I have to put in it the b.barracudacentral.org URL to activate the check of incoming mail. I use an external ISP DNS server and an external hosted email service, both outside the LAN controlled by the above firewall.

www.barracudacentral.org service require that "I register the list of IP addresses of your domain name servers (DNS servers) that will be making queries.".

I think that I have to register the IP address of my firewall that queries the b.barracudacentral.org service, and not the DNS or email external services.

It is correct my assumption ?

Comment: If your mail is hosted elsewhere, **thats** where you should be using this service , not on your router. Your router knows nothing about SMTP.

Comment: Thank you EEA, but every incoming email is filtered by an AntiSPAM filter inside the firewall and it can query a DNSBL services as b.barracudacentral.org asking me to put the URL of the preffered DNSBL service

Comment: If your mail is hosted elsewhere, it is not passing through your firewall.

Comment: I'll try to explain better: my users are inside a LAN protected by a ZyXEL  firewall. They get the emails using POP3 from an external email service. ZyXEL firewall scan every email using a AntiSpam engine. I can put in the firewall the URL of a DNSBL service to check the reputation of every single email. Do I need to register the IP Address of the ZyXEL firewall to use the b.barracudacentral.org service ?

Comment: I think you're missing the point. DNSBLs are for checking mail as it arrives to an MTA via the SMTP protocol. It is not meant to intercept MUA traffic, which uses IMAP/POP3.